# ArcSDE - AutoIncrementing Object ID in table stored in ORACLE when doing INSERT or UPDATE or DELETE using FME SDE Writer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form, oracle-spatial

I have data in an Oracle table (11 million records) and would like to insert 2000 
records approximately using the FME ArcSDE Writer to maintain ObjectID put on the Oracle table by ArcSDE via ArcGIS. I have been using FME ArcSDE writer to write the insert records to the Oracle table. I have encountered a problem of Object ID not auto incrementing to show new sequential object ids for the records inserted. I would like object id to be maintained when doing INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE operations via FME

I am not sure why this is happening and how to resolve.

Should I be using FME Oracle Writer?

Comment: For the default value to populate correctly, the registered rowid column must not be in the list of insert columns (or, with much more difficulty, you'd need to invoke the stored procedure to retrieve the next rowid value before each insert). The ArcSDE writer should know how to correctly handle this; I doubt a pure OCI function would.

Comment: Thanks Vince I'll look into trying what you suggested and will let you know how i get on. I am looking at this today and seeing if the issue can be resolved.

Comment: Always grateful for any other suggestions, thoughts, etc on this

Comment: Is this a regular Oracle table, or a Geodatabase table stored on Oracle? And are you using the Esri Geodatabase (ArcSDE Geodb) not the SDE30 format writer? My thinking too is that the writer should handle it, at least for INSERTs. Do you have the Object ID Field setting set in the writer feature types? Perhaps FME just doesn't know that it is the ID field otherwise? That's just about the only reference to Object ID that I can see in the writer documentation.

Comment: Hi Mark I have a ESRI FGDB polygon featureclass with 11 million records and want 
to store this in Oracle.  I am using an FME ArcSDE writer to write the
 ESRI featureclass to the Oracle Spatial DB. I am not sure if I should retain
 the Object_ID that the FME_ArcSDE writer adds to the output table that is 
being stored in Oracle. I want to be able to insert and update records on
 Oracle ArcSDE table and for object ids to be maintained when I insert 
records using FME_ArcSDE_writer with Insert option on the writer selected or update records selected on another writer for update queries

Comment: At the moment when I insert records, the object_ids from my insert records 
(held in separate staging table) are inserted instead of incrementing from 
the last object id in the MASTER Oracle ArcSDE table (table where inserts are 
going into). Not sure what is the best approach and if I should be using 
obectid at all to manage insert, update and delete when using ArcSDE?
 I have read somewhere that ObjectID can be a problem when doing editing
 and splitting features etc. I am not looking to edit the polygon features. 
The data is to be used a queryable backdrop basemap